# What is a real use case for std::unordered_(set|map) range based erase?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Found that `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` has range-based `erase(first, last)` which in my opinion is another nice way to shoot yourself in leg.

Maybe somebody know any real use case for such functionality?

Or this may be considered as bad design?

Comment: The range-based erase is part of the general unordered container requirements, and it's easy to provide and implement. I suppose it would be harder to explicitly *remove* this overload from the unique-key maps than to just leave it in, even though it isn't of much use. You'll notice that it isn't actually mentioned in the sections on unordered map and set.

Comment: Im willing to accept this comment as correct answer, but can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I [have an answer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase).  In C++14, it is clarified that elements that are not erased keep the same order “this makes it possible to erase individual elements while iterating through the container.”

So, your iteration will be in some random order.  But, you can delete all the ones you visited in one call.  The range to delete will be the same ones as the range you iterated.

Comment: in other words while iterating over "random-ordered"  sequence i need to track range just to perform delete in one operation? this probably can boost on large sequences... but this highly depends on distribution of data which should be deleted.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, neither does distribution. Suppose you collect a list of houses to paint, and keep that in an unordered map while data is coming in. When the paint process is triggered, it takes *any* 10 items (if there are more than that) and issues work orders for crews **and** removes them from the list. You have `begin` through howver far you step the forward iterator, processing `*it` in the loop.  Then, erase `begin (), it` to remove just those processed. That is more efficient than erasing each as you advance the iterator.

Comment: Yes, i caugth idea, thanks. However still this looks like very specific task (why 10 houses? why not all? - if all then `clear()` - would be better) - but this task may happen. Thanks, again.

Comment: Just to use concrete values. In general you can take some but not all, and which and what order doesn't matter.  10 crews available, represents some resource.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is to provide compatibility with regular map and set.

But I still think it's useful in principle.  If a range of values is retired, you want to remove them from the collection.  But the normal use case is looking up (a million times more common than insert/delete) and it is not traversed, so the unordered version is good.

How can it shoot you?  It's no different from erasing each one in a loop.  Ah, the plain start,end range forward traversal won't work, so you think the supplied function doesn't do what it takes to get it right, but does the same forward-range traversal that would work on a map but break on an unordered_map?

Gee, does it?

Comment: Yes, switching between std::map and std::unordered_map is not possible when using range-based erase() because in case of unordered collection you will get very-hard-to-predict results